# Android Shared Preferences Not Comitting

Tags: java, android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I have a switch i am toggling in the app. When i close the app i want the last toggle state to save. When the app opens it will set the toggle state to the last saved state. I am using SharedPreferences to do this. For some reason my preferences are not saving. I have looked over my code and could not find any problems.

```
// Set some preferences
    Preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(getPackageName(), 0);

    // Set the monitor toggle to on or off
    final SwitchCompat monitorToggle = (SwitchCompat)findViewById(R.id.monitorToggleButton);
    boolean monitorStatus = Preferences.getBoolean("monitorStatus", true);
    monitorToggle.setChecked(monitorStatus);

    // Setup the monitor toggle view
    LinearLayout monitorToggleView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.monitorToggle);
    monitorToggleView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            monitorToggle.toggle();
            Preferences.edit().putBoolean("monitorStatus", monitorToggle.isChecked());
            Preferences.edit().commit();
        }
    });
```

The "Preferences" variable is a private variable in the class

```
private SharedPreferences Preferences;
```

Comment: You could also change commit to apply() as it is faster when you don't check for a result. Commit give a boolean return (true for success), apply does not. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourActivity.this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

editor.putBoolean("monitorStatus", monitorToggle.isChecked());
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct but omit to explain that the mistake was to call `edit()` twice, i.e. you have created a second `Editor`, made no changes, and commited. You never committed the changes to the first `Editor`.

Instead of this:

```
Preferences.edit().putBoolean("monitorStatus", monitorToggle.isChecked());
Preferences.edit().commit();
```

you could just do:

```
Preferences.edit().putBoolean("monitorStatus", monitorToggle.isChecked()).commit();
```

There's no need to store the `Editor` in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Editor editor = Preferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("monitorStatus", false);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Both this answer and the previous answer work! Thanks!